# Array out of Bound Exception using Enum

Tags: java

I keep on getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException and I don't know why. It is getting frustrating.

here are my static Arrays:

```
private static final String[] RANK_CODES = {"a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "t", "j", "q", "k"};
private static final String[] SUIT_CODES = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
```

now when I try to access them:

```
 private static String getCode(Card pCard) {
          return RANK_CODES[pCard.getRank().ordinal()] + 
          SUIT_CODES[pCard.getSuit().ordinal()];
}
```

My Card object has a rank and a suit both of which are enums.

Any clue why this happens?

Comment: When you debug the code what's returning `pCard.getRank().ordinal()` and `pCard.getSuit().ordinal()` inside `getCode`?

Comment: it will output the codes until the ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Either your enums have more entries than the String arrays or there is some kind of problematic initialization order (e.g. using RANK_CODES before it is initialized)

Comment: Print out your two values: pCard.getRank().ordinal() and pCard.getSuit().ordinal(). That will almost certainly tell you the problem.

Comment: I saved my images as codes which are letter combinations of Rank and Suit, so for example if I have an image for 8 of Spades, I named it 8s

Comment: What I meant is `pCard.getRank().ordinal()` must return a number between `0` and `12` and `pCard.getSuit().ordinal()` must return a value between `0` and `3`, is that so?

Comment: @ScrappyMontana paste full stacktrace, as there is index clue :)

Comment: @ScrappyMontana anyway, why pCard? Are you fan of Startrek or something (cpt. p(i)Card)

Comment: guys the problem was because  I added "Joker" to my enums but my Array lengths didn't match. Now that I know my problem I don't know how to properly add a code for my Joker cards, any clue how? If I add another letter to my RANK_CODES or SUIT_CODES, it messes up the urls for the other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include the code for your Card and Rank/Suit enums.  It looks like your RANK_CODES or SUIT_CODES arrays contain fewer values than the corresponding enum.  Ie., your SUIT_CODES array contains 4 values but your SUIT enum has 5 or 6 values in it.  So, the ordinal of a SUIT might come back as 6 which isn't a valid index into an array with 4 values.

Jokers don't really have a suit or rank so I would probably alter the Card object if possible and add a boolean field for isJoker.  Then change the logic in your getCode() to check if isJoker is true and return the appropriate value, maybe just "j" or "joker".  I don't see in the code you've posted how these values end up picking images so we wold need to see more code to answer that part.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, that `pCard.getSuit()]` is not of type `SUIT_CODES` but of `RANK_CODES` or is some other enum. Double check that `Card` has proper enum as suits